# Path : "/sdcard/" works in all devices?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have used this code in my app.

Is it  **OKAY** for all the devices ?Will it works on all the devices ?

```
String path= "/sdcard/.beta1/data/text/myfile.txt";
File myFile = new File(path);
myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
myFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

I have also tried `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();` but I am confused which one is better and more stable?

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();`,  its better in my opinion...

Comment: Please explain me how to use it ? In some posts I have seen that some times it returns path of internal storage ?

Comment: of course, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it OKAY for all the devices ?Will it works on all the devices ?

No. Not only will it not work on all devices, but it will not work for all *users* of all devices. Most Android devices support multiple users; different users will have different paths for [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**.

Use [`getExternalCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)), or [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to work with files on external storage. The first two have the advantage of not requiring any permissions on API Level 19 and higher.

Comment: Ok thanks, one more query - 'String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/.beta/";' is same as 'path="/sdcard/.beta/"; ?

Comment: @Amar: Do not create a string. You need a `File`. Use `File betaDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".beta");`.

Answer (score 1):

To read file:

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                          .getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```

`filename` it's a `String` variable

Or you can use too:

```
File sdCardDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyFolder/" + "MyFile.txt");
```